# Output is not as expected in the prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, prediction, calibration

I have  train and test datasets like this:

```
train: 2000 files
hit.txt
nohit.txt
hit.txt

Test: 1500 
hit.txt
nohit.txt
hit.txt
```

I trained a model and got accuracy of 74 percent; here is the code below:

But when i do my prediction on test data set, the scores i get is an array which i do not want.

```
test_dir = 'test/'
dictionary = make_dic(test_dir)

features_, labels_ = make_dataset(dictionary)

calibrated_pred_final = calibrated_clf_pipe.predict(features_)

calibrated_pred_final
array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0])

test_pred_final = calibrated_clf_pipe.predict_proba(features_)
import numpy as np
batch_y = np.array(test_pred_final).flatten()

f = open('scores.txt', 'w')
for i in range(len(batch_y)):
    f.write(str(batch_y))
```

score.txt file looks like this,

```
[0.38636364 0.61363636 0.05147059 ... 0.61363636 0.86734694 0.13265306][0.38636364 0.61363636 0.05147059 ... 0.61363636 0.86734694 0.13265306][0.38636364 0.61363636 0.05147059 ... 0.61363636 0.86734694 0.13265306][0.38636364 0.61363636 0.05147059 ... 0.61363636 0.86734694 0.13265306][0.38636364 0.61363636 0.05147059 ... 0.61363636 0.86734694 0.13265306][0.38636364 0.61363636 0.05147059 ... 0.61363636 0.86734694 0.13265306][0.38636364 0.61363636 0.05147059 ... 0.61363636 0.86734694 0.13265306][0.38636364 0.61363636 0.05147059 ... 0.61363636 0.86734694 0.13265306][0.38636364 0.61363636 0.05147059 ... 0.61363636 0.86734694 0.13265306][0.38636364 0.61363636 0.05147059 ... 0.61363636 0.86734694 0.13265306][0.38636364 0.61363636 0.05147059 ... 0.61363636 0.86734694 0.13265306][0.38636364 0.61363636 0.05147059 ... 0.61363636 0.86734694 0.13265306][0.38636364 0.61363636 0.05147059 ... 0.61363636 0.86734694 0.13265306] this goes forever.
```

What I expect is a score per test mail as shown below.

```
 0.38636364     
 0.61363636 
 0.05147059
    ...
    ...
```

I am not sure what is going wrong. Why I am getting this score in an array  which repeats 1500 times? I assume that this array of scores represents score per mail but how do I remove the entire list and just have one score per mail like my expected results?

Answer (score 0):

The predictions are as expected. The issue is in the way you write to `score.txt`. You missed indexing into `batch_y`, so it is adding the entire array for every element in the array. Here is the updated code:

```py
test_dir = 'test/'
dictionary = make_dic(test_dir)

features_, labels_ = make_dataset(dictionary)

calibrated_pred_final = calibrated_clf_pipe.predict(features_)

calibrated_pred_final
array([1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0])

# line changed below.
test_pred_final = calibrated_clf_pipe.predict_proba(features_)

import numpy as np
batch_y = np.array(test_pred_final).flatten()

f = open('scores.txt', 'w')
for i in range(len(batch_y)):
    f.write(str(batch_y[i]) + '\n') # You missed indexing into batch_y here
```

You can continue using `predict_proba` if you want probabilities. If you want 0 1 predictions, use `predict`.

Comment: My test data does have 1500 data points however each of them is a separate text file. So I expect the output to be as shown above.

Comment: with your indexing code, my output still looks like this [0.42857143 0.94117647 0.0625     ... 0.84210526 0.71875    0.62      ][0.42857143 0.94117647 0.0625     ... 0.84210526 0.71875    0.62      ][0.42857143 0.94117647 0.0625     ... 0.84210526 0.71875    0.62      ][0.42857143 0.94117647 0.0625     ... 0.84210526 0.71875    0.62      ][0.42857143 0.94117647 0.0625     ... 0.84210526 0.71875    0.62      ][0.42857143 0.94117647 0.0625     ... 0.84210526 0.71875    0.62      ][0.42857143 0.94117647 0.0625     ... 0.84210526 0.71875    0.62      ]

Comment: Right. Then you need to extract the index with the highest probability. Then why are you using `predict_proba`? You should use `predict`

Comment: do you know why we get these many probabilities for one single data point row?.

Comment: It is based on the classifier you are using. Generally, when using `predict_proba`, you get the probability of each class in your dataset being positive. That is why you are getting so many probabilities (for each class). If you use `predict`, then it only gives the class with the highest probability.

Comment: but i have only 2 classes right ham or spam and why i get so many prob?

Comment: My guess is that there is something else wrong in the `make_dataset` function, due to which it is predicting so many classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236203/discussion-between-ayush-goel-and-ksp).